# Removing Duplicate Files on MacOS Terminal Using MD5

Tags: macos, terminal.app, deduplication

I found the following command that makes use of md5 file hashes to find duplicate files and list them in a text file.

```
find ./ -type f -exec md5 {} \; | awk -F '=' '{print $2 "\t" $1}' | sort | tee duplicates.txt
```

However, since every file with the same hash is listed, I am unable to use the following command to remove the duplicate files as every line in the text file would be deleted including the original.

```
while read file; do rm "$file"; done < duplicates.txt
```

Is there a way to remove all but the first file with a duplicate md5 hash in the duplicates.txt file?

Comment: The wheel you're reinventing: [`jdupes`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jdupes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fdupes` may be your solution. It can be installed via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with

```
brew install fdupes
```

If you don’t have homebrew, you can install homebrew with

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

You can use the `-d` option to be prompted which files to keep (deleting all others), and the `-N` option deletes all but the first without prompting. `-r` recursively searches the specified directory(ies).

So `fdupes -rdN <directory>` should delete all but the first in each set of duplicates. Be careful when deleting without prompting, of course. Maybe copy the directory first if the files are important.

*I’m sorry to suggest a third-party tool; I usually try to find a way to do things without additional software, but fdupes is the only way I know. I’ll think of a way to use your md5 list for the same purpose.*